# javascript var into input value

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, input

can someone help me out getting a javascript var inside the value of a form
input value?

I'm a newbie in javascript but can give you my solution in php.
("Just use php" isn't an option because it have to be client-based :D )

```
<?php
$value = "Hello!";
?>

<form name="settings" action="">
   <input name="color" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
document.forms["settings"].color.value = "your value goes here...";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$value = "Hello!";
?>

<form name="settings" action="">
   <input name="color" value="" />
</form>  
<script>
document.forms["settings"].color.value = "<?php echo $value;?>";
</script>
```